# Nginx second proxy_pass not working

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx

I have nginx, apache, and node setup on my CentOS server.

Node runs on port 8080.

In my default.conf nginx file, I have

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

That works. When going to my site's homepage (and any other page that node uses, such as /login and /signup page), I see my node app correctly.

I have a couple of other rules like this one, in order to let nginx serve the static files instead of node serving them.

```
location /javascripts {
    root /var/www/myWebsite/public;
}
```

I am setting up a forum, and I'm using apache and php for it. The forum works at myWebsite.com:90, however I want to make the forum work without the port number.
Apache has Listen 90, and DocumentRoot is set to the forum path.

Nginx conf has this

```
location /forum {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:90;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

But that doesn't work, I get a 404. If I go to some giberrish page, I get the node's error page, so we can see that something is working by getting the 'normal' web 404 instead of my custom node's 404.

How can I remove that :90 port now?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
upstream apache_server {
  server 127.0.0.1:90;
  keepalive 60;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://apache_server
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of just plainly specifying the rule; maybe you should add some information on where this has to be added, what purpose does it solve or whatever it conveys. In isolation, this doesn't make much sense as an answer. Just a suggestion :)